# Get Id from MenuItem and Go To Next Activity

Tags: android, android-menu

I have created a `Menu` with 4 `menuitems`.I need to retrieve the `menuitems` Id upon being `pressed` and then a check must happen to see the what Id has been `pressed` and go to a new `Activity`. I have tried using`item.getTitle()` and `item.getItemId()` but it does not go into the `if statement`.

#### popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:title="TOOL 7 - THE FORCE"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:title="TOOL 5 - FOCUS"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:title="TOOL 3 - ACTION"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:title="TOOL 9 - QUESTION FIX"/>

</menu>
```

#### Code to retrieve MenuItemId

```
 btnToolbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToolbox);
    btnToolbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Screen2_11.this,btnToolbox);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    itemName = String.valueOf(item.getTitle());
                    itemId = item.getItemId();
                    if ( itemName == "TOOL 7 - THE FORCE" || itemId == "one" ){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen108_Force.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else if ( itemName == "TOOL 5 - FOCUS" || itemId == "two" ) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen120_Focus.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else if ( itemName == "TOOL 3 - ACTION" || itemId == "three" ) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen119_Action.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else if ( itemName == "TOOL 9 - QUESTION FIX" || itemId == "four" ) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen136_Questions.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **`if (itemId == R.id.one)`** instead of `if ( itemName == "TOOL 7 - THE FORCE" || itemId == "one" )`

Try this

```
    btnToolbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Screen2_11.this, btnToolbox);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                   int itemId = item.getItemId();

                    if (itemId == R.id.one) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen108_Force.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.two) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen120_Focus.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.three) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen119_Action.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.four) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Screen136_Questions.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man working perfectly.

Comment: @AnonymousZA happy to help you

Comment: will do just have to wait 3 mins to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the menu first. Add this portion after finishing your onCreate()

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}
```

then handle the item pressed options here.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //here initialize your button pressed.

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```